# Where is the most up-to-date reputation count?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Is it

1. The number in the SE nav bar on SO?
2. The number in the SE nav bar on MSO? (Which always seems to be different than the first)
3. The number on https://stackoverflow.com/reputation?

Thanks!

Comment: Number 1, usually.

Comment: Is (1) different from (3) on your end? Because it shouldn't be.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Often...

Answer (score 3):

The number you find on [https://stackoverflow.com/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation?) is always up-to-date as that is where you can audit your own reputation. I expect the data on that page to come from the db and the query is executed when you hit that page.

The number in the SE nav bar might be off based on if you just refreshed or not. Updates to the number are send over the [websocket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218355/158100). If that misses a heartbeat your reputation counter will be off.

The reputation shown on MSO is always off. It gets synced, IIRC, in the 15 minute job.